# Adding value y to lambda x recursively with scheme

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, racket

I have been trying various combinations but can't seem to find the right one. What I am trying to do is add variable y to each element in list x and print out the list with the result (y+x_1 + y+x_2 ... y+x_n).

Here is my scheme code:

```
(define (incall y) 
  (lambda (x)
    (if (null? (cdr x))
       x ;;Tried several variations
    (+ y x) ;;Same here (using car/cdr /cons)
    )
  )
)
```

The numbers I am implementing are:

```
    ((incall 2) '(1 2 3))
```

and should yield.

```
    (2 3 4)
```

Any help is appreciated and an explanation on what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Trying various combinations for a simple function typically means that you haven't understood the core material. Are you sure you know how a list or function works in lisp?

Comment: Not quite no, I loose the thread when we start using other variables and lambda. The material I have does not cover this well enough. If you have any advice where I can read more about it and the function it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [sicp](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your curried procedure so that you can use it for the rest of the list from itself:

```
(define (add-list intial-value) 
  (define (curried-proc lst)
     ...)
  curried-proc) ; return the proc
```

I don't know why you would want this interface. I would have preferred  doing `(add-list 2 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (3 4 5)`, then you'd do this:

```
(define (add-list initial-value lst) 
  (define (helper lst)
     ...)
  (helper lst)) ; return the result of calling helper
```

So to the helper.. You need to handle the first element only and recurse for the rest if not null. For null it should be null. eg.

```
(define (helper lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
      <??>                        ; what is the result of (incall 5 '())
      (cons <calculate>           ; what whould (car x) be replaced with?
            (helper (cdr lst)))))
```

Now the helper can be replaced by a named `let`. It's the same. Here is a working version of something similar to what you are making:

```
(define (halve-list lst)
  (let helper ((lst lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (/ (car lst) 2)
              (helper (cdr lst))))))

(halve-list '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (1/2 1 3/2 2)
```

Another way to do this is with `map` as it takes care of most of the helper except what to do with each element:

```
(define (halve-list lst)
  (map (lambda (e) (/ e 2)) lst))
```

Comment: Thanks @Sylwester. This puts me on the right track. I will give my results when I finish them. Again thanks a million!